# How do I add a class to a selected <li> tag depending on the users page visit?

Tags: jquery, loops

I am having some issue with looping in JQuery, which I have never done before! What I want to do is add an '.activelink' class to a menu `<li>` tag when the user is on that selected page.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

  var Header = $('#PageTitle').html();
  var Menu  

   $('li').each(function (i) {
        //alert (i++); 
      Menu = $("#' . i .'").html();
      alert (Menu);
      if (Menu == Header) {
          alert (i++);
          $('#i').addClass("ActiveLink");
      }
  });
}); //End of Doc Ready!
```

This is what I am currently working with! I know that 'Menu' does not work. I did have it just set to 'Menu = $("#i").html();' But I think this is not adding the id number to the selector but making JQuery try to target 'i' has the ID!

So How do I get the number count inside the selector?

Many Thanks

Glenn.

Comment: `$("#' . i .'").html();` should be `$("#" + i).html();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have got your quotes muddled up in your selector;

```
Menu = $("#" + i).html();
```

Also, `.` is the PHP concatenation operator. JavaScript just uses `+`.

Same again in your `if`;

```
if (Menu == Header) {
      alert (i++);
      $('#' + i).addClass("ActiveLink");
  }
```

Note how it doesn't matter whether you use `'` or `"`, as long as the opening and closing ones match.

Comment: Many Thanks - I give this ago! Yes I am more PHP / CakePHP backend coder than front end. I know there must be a way of doing that I wanted by adding the 'i' has a count not as the selector! Thanks Glenn.

Answer (score 0):

Wrong operator `.` it should be `+`

```
 Menu = $("#" + i).html();
```

Change this too -

```
$("#" + i).addClass("ActiveLink");
```